# Using runtime to open file in its native application. (Windows 7)

Tags: java, windows-7, applet

## Background

I have an old applet that I want to revive. All functionality works in Windows XP. However, in Windows 7 it doesn't work to open a file in its native application (part of code below). Nothing happens, no error or anything similar. I am using *Java version 1.5.0 (J2SE 5.0)*, thus *Desktop.getDesktop();* will not work!

## Code

```
public void start(String sFileName, String sDir, ctgraphics gGfx) {
    String command = '"' + sDir + sFileName + '"';
    Runtime myRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        myRuntime.exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + command);
        gGfx.setStatusText("File opened.");
        gGfx.drawStatusBar(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

## Question

Why doesn't the above code work in Windows 7 and what do I need to do instead to be able to open a file in its native application (considering I am using Java v. 1.5) ?

.

Cheers.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) { ..e.getMessage()..` Even though the code is producing no exception output at the moment, I recommend to change that last part to add: `e.printStackTrace();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the Desktop support, look at this link:

[Desktop.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29)

You just create a `File` with the path of the file you want to open and then call `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`.

Before 1.5 desktop was a Library that then it made it into the standard JDK, you can consider using this option.

Here you can find a tutorial:

[javadesktop tutorial for java one 2004](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGwQFjAI&url=http://javadesktop.org/jdic/presentations/BOF-9871_JDIC_JavaOne05.pdf&ei=JJaaT9GvE4WcgQf1suHoDg&usg=AFQjCNFYRY0WOBUqpHO02K48uq_647-O1A&sig2=VO_-k3w-7NU1if5Ie5c2gg)

Hope this helps

And here is the project site:

[JDIC Project](http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/index.html)

Here you can find the jars:

[Maven repo with jdic jars](http://www.astrogrid.org/maven/jdic/)

Comment: `Desktop` is 1.6+ & the OP explicitly states "I am using *Java version 1.5.0 (J2SE 5.0)*, thus *Desktop.getDesktop();* will not work!".  Please delete this 'not an answer'.

Comment: Before 1.6 it was a separate lib you can add to your project.

Comment: If you hunt down a link to that, I could up-vote.  Good edit so far. :)

Comment: Here is a tutorial from 2004, just a curious question, is it not possible for you to use java 6?

Comment: Ah, JDIC again.  Did you follow any of the links to the JDIC homepage?  It is a 404.

Comment: *"is it not possible for you to use java 6?"*  I was just quoting the question, though I'd discussed it briefly with the OP on another of their questions.

Comment: Hmm, It has been a long time since JDK6 came out and incorporated that framework, maybe it's just down, but you can try finding the jar library on the internet, for example a maven repository

Comment: Updated the post with a link to the jars.

Comment: I tried this. Added the *jdic-0.9.1.jar* as a library and added `Desktop.open(new File(file));` . I received the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/jdic/desktop/internal/impl/ServiceManagerStub
 at org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.internal.ServiceManager.getService(Unknown Source)
 at org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
 at testing.testing1.main(testing1.java:16)` .

Comment: Hmm maybe you need to include another jar.

Comment: I made it work once, but it was really a long time ago, I don't remeber but the exception you're getting indicates a missing class so I can think of it as you need to include some extra jar.

Comment: Ok, I got a different error now. I added the jdic_stub_Windows-0.9.1.jar and got the following error: `org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.DesktopException: The given file doesn't exist.
 at org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.Desktop.checkFileValid(Unknown Source)
 at org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
 at testing.testing1.main(testing1.java:17)`

Comment: Hmm is the source available??

Comment: The source code or do you mean the source as in the file itself? The source code is pretty much whats above but with the use of Desktop.open instead of myRuntime.exec. The file itself is available, yes.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it! I had to include the jdic.dll in the project (I'm using Eclipse so I just dragged it to the project). Apart from this I had to include the jdic-0.9.1.jar and the jdic_stub_Windows-0.9.1.jar Thanks a lot Juan! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). It describes many of the common pittfals.

Answer (score 1):

1. The single line call to `RunTime.exec()` rarely works.  Be sure to read and implement all the suggestions of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).
2. Break up arguments into an array, for easier/more predictable parsing.
3. Since 1.5, the J2SE has offered [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which offers methods such as [`redirectErrorStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29).  That method in turn makes it easier to implement some of the recommendations of point 1.